# Getting the Error when I get selectors from createEntityAdapter in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

While developing a simple pet project, I faced an error, without knowing how to fix it.
I am new to Typescript, and judging by a message error the mistake is in TS.
The error message appears after adding this snippet into the file 'apiSlice.ts'.

```
export const { selectAll: selectAllPizzas } = pizzasAdapter.getSelectors(
    state => selectPizzasData(state) ?? initialState
)
```

The error text looks like this:

```
ERROR in src/features/api/apiSlice.ts:44:31
TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ api: CombinedState<{ getPizzas: QueryDefinition<void, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown,
 FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, never, PizzaResponseType[], "api">; }, never, "api">; }'.
    42 | //
    43 | export const { selectAll: selectAllPizzas } = pizzasAdapter.getSelectors(
  > 44 |     state => selectPizzasData(state) ?? initialState
       |                               ^^^^^
    45 | )
    46 |
```

The whole file: (Pay attention to the last three rows)

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { createEntityAdapter, createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const pizzasAdapter = createEntityAdapter()
const initialState = pizzasAdapter.getInitialState()

interface PizzaResponseType {
    id: string
    name: string
    image: string
    price: number
    currencySign: string
    popularityPoint: number
    type: string
    description: string
    spec: string
}
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '' }),
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getPizzas: builder.query<PizzaResponseType[], void>({
            query: () => '/pizzas',
            transformResponse: (responseData: PizzaResponseType[]) => {
                pizzasAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData)
                return responseData
            },
        }),
    }),
})

export const { useGetPizzasQuery } = apiSlice

export const selectPizzasResult = apiSlice.endpoints.getPizzas.select()

// console.log(selectPizzasResult)

export const selectPizzasData = createSelector(
    selectPizzasResult,
    pizzasResult => pizzasResult.data
)
//
export const { selectAll: selectAllPizzas } = pizzasAdapter.getSelectors(
    state => selectPizzasData(state) ?? initialState
)
```

The RootState was imported from the store.ts file, where I configured the store as it was witten in the Redux Toolkit documentation.
The store.ts file:

```
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        pizzas:pizzaSlice,
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
})
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export default store
```

That imported RootState type was inserted for the state in the parameter:

```
export const { selectAll: selectAllPizzas } = pizzasAdapter.getSelectors(
    (state: RootState) => selectPizzasData(state) ?? initialState
)
```

and this change does nothing. The error appears anyway:

```
ERROR in src/features/api/apiSlice.ts:46:5
TS2345: Argument of type '(state: RootState) => EntityState<unknown> | PizzaResponseType[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { pizzas: EntityState<unknown>; api: CombinedState<{ getPizzas: Query
Definition<void, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, never, PizzaResponseType[], "api">; }, never, "api">; }) => EntityState<...>'.
  Type 'EntityState<unknown> | PizzaResponseType[]' is not assignable to type 'EntityState<unknown>'.
    Type 'PizzaResponseType[]' is missing the following properties from type 'EntityState<unknown>': ids, entities
    44 |
    45 | export const { selectAll: selectAllPizzas } = pizzasAdapter.getSelectors(
  > 46 |     (state: RootState) => selectPizzasData(state) ?? initialState
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    47 | )
```

How to fix it?

In case you want to run the pet project. Follow this link:https://github.com/AlexKor-5/ReactPizzaApp_Ts/tree/27028d4275fef75a70eb6b0b4b129e5bf5997e78  (but change the end of the apiSlice file so it corresponds to the file which is shown on the current page of Stack Overflow).
(src/features/api/apiSlice.ts )

Also when I write `<EntityState<PizzaResponseType>` how it is supposed to be. Look at the example:

```
getPizzas: builder.query<EntityState<PizzaResponseType>, void>({
            query: () => '/pizzas',
            transformResponse: (responseData: PizzaResponseType[]) => {
                return pizzasAdapter.setAll(pizzaInitialState,responseData)
            },
        }),
```

I get another error:

```
TS2322: Type '(responseData: IPizzaType[]) => EntityState<unknown>' is not assignable to type '(baseQueryReturnV
alue: unknown, meta: FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined, arg: void) => EntityState<IPizzaType> | Promise<EntityState
<IPizzaType>>'.
  Type 'EntityState<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'EntityState<IPizzaType> | Promise<EntityState<IPizzaTyp
e>>'.
    Type 'EntityState<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'EntityState<IPizzaType>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IPizzaType'.
    28 |         getPizzas: builder.query<EntityState<IPizzaType>, void>({
    29 |             query: () => '/pizzas',
  > 30 |             transformResponse: (responseData: IPizzaType[]) => {
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    31 |                 return pizzasAdapter.setAll(pizzaInitialState, responseData)
    32 |             },
    33 |         }),
```

What is wrong again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from @phry 's initial response, I think the issue is your `transformResponse` function:

```
            transformResponse: (responseData: PizzaResponseType[]) => {
                pizzasAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData)
                return responseData
            },
```

That code has a couple problems:

- You're returning the *original* `responseData`, which is still a `PizzaResponseType[]`.  That tells TS that the result is *also* a `PizzaResponseType[]`, when what it *should* be is an `EntityState<Pizza>`.
- In order to make that happen, you need to return the value from `pizzasAdapter.setAll()` instead.

Comment: In my answer below I wrote this: `getPizzas: builder.query<EntityState<unknown>, void>({
            query: () => '/pizzas',
            transformResponse: (responseData: PizzaResponseType[]) => {
                return pizzasAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData)
            },
        }),` , but I guess, 'unknow value is not right' in `<EntityState<unknown>`. What should use instead?

Comment: I guess some custom type should be there, but I do not know how it should look. Could you write an example of that type?

Comment: I _think_ you still want `PizzaResponseType[]` in the `builder.query` generic, but I _think_ that gets overridden by the return value of `transformResponse`.

Comment: I return this: `pizzasAdapter.setAll()` and upper where the query is defined I went for this: ` builder.query<EntityState<unknown>, void> `. Is it ok to put **unknown** in generic?  I guess no. Because when I want to access one of the properties in the Entity state, Typescript doesn't allow me to do it because of an unknown type. So how to solve it?

Comment: The entity type is whatever one individual item is supposed to be - in this case, `PizzaResponseType`.  So, `EntityState<PizzaResponseType>`.

Comment: I did what you recommended. I got access to properties, but I got another error about transformResponse. Read the last part of my question above. (The one was extended)

Comment: Your `createEntityAdapter` call is missing the generic type. You _must_ provide that: `const pizzasAdapter = createEntityAdapter<PizzaResponse>()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give a type for `state`.

```
(state: RootState) => selectPizzasData(state) ?? initialState
```

Comment: I gave a type for the state in the parameter. It has done nothing. My question was a bit edited by making what you recommended, and you can check this out again.

Answer (score 1):

I redid it in this way:

```
getPizzas: builder.query<EntityState<unknown>, void>({
            query: () => '/pizzas',
            transformResponse: (responseData: PizzaResponseType[]) => {
                return pizzasAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData)
            },
        }),
```

and plus this snippet:

```
export const { selectAll: selectAllPizzas } = pizzasAdapter.getSelectors(
    (state: RootState) => selectPizzasData(state) ?? initialState
)
```

After all of those changes, the error disappeared.